# Superfluid Fountain

Tags: energy-conservation, bose-einstein-condensate, perpetual-motion, superfluidity

I was wondering how a super fluid fountain can flow indefinitely without violating energy conservation.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fountain is sealed off with a plug that blocks the normal fluid (and lets the superfluid pass). The plug is heated, which is the source of energy that powers the fountain.

Comment: Thanks, So there is nothing special other than the fact it has no frictional losses but same as a regular fountain. A lot of misleading information out there..

Comment: how doesn't the heat power ruin the super-fluidity state?!

Comment: At any temperature below the lambda point (2.2K) liquid helium is a mixture of a superfluid and a normal fluid. The superfluid fraction goes to zero as $T\to T_c$. If you set up a temperature gradient, then the normal fluid flows to low T, and the superfluid flows to high T. This is why the superfluid flows into the heated pipe. The seal ensures that the normal fluid cannot get out, and you get the fountain effect.